# passing a script value to a endpoint in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

**My Question:** I need to pass a script's value as a part of a Request's endpoint. How to perform this?

**Scenario:** I should maintain a id throughout the test suite which contains 10 or more Test cases. The ID which I get on executing the first Test case, should be passed as a part of the endpoint for the next coming test cases, say `wwww.google.com/{id}`

**I tried:** Creating the test suite and test cases, then adding HTTP Test request test step for each test cases. And then, after the test case has finished executing, the response is written to a `xml` file by using a Groovy script as a test step. BTW both the request and response are in `JSON` format not in XML. After writing the response to a file, I use another script to read the response from the file, and parse the `JSON` content to get only the value I need. Then I added the parameter to the endpoint for the next Test step, say `www.google.com/$id`. However, this failed!

Now,how to pass this value as a part of the next test step's endpoint? Please guide me on this.

Comment: it's not clear to me what you do with the value once you parse the JSON after reading from file.  Might help to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1):

soapUI Example:

1) Test Case: **Authentication**

Response (json): {"sessionID": "7722f396-a32e-4533-a16b-e5141e00d691"}

2) Test Case: **Get Status**

Request URL in soapUI = http://url/session/${Authentication#Response#$.sessionID}

Result URL = http://url/session/7722f396-a32e-4533-a16b-e5141e00d691

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you shouldn't need an external file for this.  According to [this](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html) (see "3. Script access to properties" section), you should have write access to properties you define, at some scope of your choosing, from scripts (it's not clear to me if you need to have defined them statically via the UI, or whether you can create new ones on the fly).  I believe those values should then be usable in defining your endpoint. (scopes shown [here](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html))

(There's also [`Property-Transfer`](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transfering-property-values.html) steps, but these may not suit your JSON requirements, due to apparent reliance on XPath to extract the values.)

Comment: SoapUI internally converts everything into XML. So even a JSON response is converted, and you can find tings there using XPath.